# Modification of Latin adage

Tags: classical-latin

Is this a good alternate Latin translation of "Never give up, never surrender?":Numquam desiste, numquam dede!

Comment: Alternate to what? What is it supposed to be a modification of? (And no, *dedere* can only mean "surrender" in a transitive sense. You'd need a *te* to go with it.)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your question seems to need a bit more context so that the rest of us can give a meaningful answer. What is the Latin adage you are referring to? Do you know other translations, or why you call 'alternate' that of yours?

Comment: The closest Latin quote i found online that expresses  the same thought is "Non desistas non exieris." I wanted to express it slightly differently and in the imperative, and was only seeking confirmation that my rusty Latin is still adequate to the task.  Thanks for responding.